# Underline Text in Label which is in a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles, datatemplate

i have a `ListView` which contains objects bound from an collection. The representation of the objects I have set with a `DataTemplate`.  Now I want to do the following.
There are two `TextBlock`s in my `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}"></TextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I already have specified an `ItemContainerStyle` which I use to realize a hover-effect.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
       <Style.Triggers>
                 <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
  ... and so on
```

My aim is to underline the `TextBlock` which contains the Name, when user moves mouse over the `ListViewItem`. The Path shouldn't be underlined. How can this be realized? How can an element in `DataTemplate` can be accessed for each `ListViewItem`?

Greetings,
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this either by specifying the ControlTemplate for the ListViewItem, or by changing the DataTemplate. The example below shows both methods. Note that you lose the blue background for the selected ListViewItem when you use the ControlTemplate (when you comment it out it returns)
EDIT:
I did not read your requirement well. You only want to underline the Name. Then the only possibility is to use the Datatemplate, or to rewrite the ControlTemplate of the TextBox.

```
<Window x:Class="Underlining.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300"
   >
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Border Name="UnderlineInControlTemplate" BorderThickness="2,0,2,0"
                                        BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="UnderlineInControlTemplate"
                                                Property="BorderBrush"
                                                Value="BlueViolet"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border Name="UnderlineInDataTemplate" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent">
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TextBlock.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="UnderlineInDataTemplate"
                                    Property="BorderBrush"
                                    Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```